# Zoom to Selected Feature Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, zoom, customize-mode

When working with quality assessment fishnet tiles in ArcMap most of the time couple of thousands i have to double click each record to move from one fishnet to the other. Instead of that i am looking for a keyboard shortcut which can do first ***go to the next record line*** and also at the same time ***zoom to that feature to a fixed scale***. In the ArcMap attribute table view ***Ctrl + Enter*** will take you the next row record the missing one is how to zoom to that feature in the map view with keyboard shortcut at the same time.

I do not have that much programming know how.